# Rendering issue in Unity particle system on UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I'm new in unity and I'm trying to build a simple winning effect using particle systems.

My effect consists of two particle systems, the first one for colored stars and the second one for balloons.

The particle system in scene view works perfectly, but in game view the ballons look like green squares.

Scene View:

[image]

Game View:

[image]

So, what is the problem in rendering the ballons?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure all Balloons are set to be Texture Type : Sprite(2D and UI)?

Comment: Actually, I'm use it as a material, so I created a material with shader -> particle/standard surface.

Comment: Is every ballon like the green one in the Game View?

Comment: Yes, it is like the green one or only small part of the green square appear.